# Using Aggregate functions in JPA

Tags: jpa, aggregate-functions

I have the folowing situation.

I want to retrieve a list of bids between time t1 and time t2. Then from this list i want to retrieve winning bid i.e maximum bid price.

I have written the following JPA query.

```
SELECT b FROM Bid b WHERE b.bidAmt = (SELECT MAX(b.bidAmt) FROM b WHERE b.lastUpdtTs BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2)
```

But I am getting the following exception.

```
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT b FROM Bid b WHERE b.bidAmt = (SELECT MAX(b.bidAmt) FROM b WHERE b.lastUpdtTs BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2)], line 1, column 64: unexpected token [b].
Internal Exception: NoViableAltException(66!=[1108:1: subselectIdentificationVariableDeclaration[List varDecls] : ( identificationVariableDeclaration[varDecls] | n= associationPathExpression ( AS )? i= IDENT | n= collectionMemberDeclaration );])
```

Couls someone point out the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you query references two different `Bid` instances, they should have different aliases:

```
SELECT b FROM Bid b WHERE b.bidAmt = 
     (SELECT MAX(bb.bidAmt) FROM Bid bb WHERE bb.lastUpdtTs BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it myself, but from what I see, mistake could be in your subquery. You say `FROM b`, but it should be `FROM Bid b`. So, the entire query looks like this:

```
SELECT b FROM Bid b WHERE b.bidAmt = (SELECT MAX(b.bidAmt) FROM Bid b WHERE b.lastUpdtTs BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2)
```

Comment: i tried the above but got the following exception Exception Description: Error compiling the query [SELECT b FROM Bid b WHERE b.bidAmt = (SELECT MAX(b.bidAmt) FROM Bid b WHERE b.lastUpdtTs BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2)], line 1, column 68: multiple declaration of identification variable [b], previously declared as [Bid b]

Answer (score 0):

The Error you got the second time is

> multiple declaration of identification
>   variable [b], previously declared as
>   [Bid b]

From the above error it seems like b alias declared for multiple times so remove alias b from sub query

try out following query

```
SELECT b FROM Bid b WHERE b.bidAmt =
    (SELECT MAX(bidAmt) FROM Bid WHERE lastUpdtTs BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2)
```